# Find values of $b$ for which $f(x) = x^3 + bx^2 + 12x + 18$ is increasing everywhere

Tags: calculus

Find value of $b$ when function is increasing for all values of $x$ for $f(x) = x^3 + bx^2 + 12x + 18$

So what I did was find the first derivative:
$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2bx^2 + 12$

made is greater than zero
$3x^2 + 2bx + 12 > 0$

did quadratic formula:

$0 < \frac{-2b \pm \sqrt{4b^2 - 144}} 6$

$2b = \pm \sqrt{4b^2 - 144}$

$4b^2 = \pm (4b^2 - 144)$

Is this right, or am I totally off?

Comment: The discriminant of $f'(x)$ must be $\le 0$.

Comment: @njguliyev why?

Comment: @njguliyev descriminant only tells you # of x-intercepts

Comment: Because only then $f'(x) \ge 0$ for *all* $x$.

Comment: You have an upward facing parabola. It is always **above** the $x$-axis iff there are no real roots, i.e. $(2b)^2-(4)(3)(12)\lt 0$. But we also allow it to just touch the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 2):

We essentially want the range of the derivative to be only positive. Hence, if we write
\begin{align}
f'(x) & = 3x^2 + 2bx + 12 = 3 \left(x^2 + 2\dfrac{b}3 x\right)+12 = 3 \left(\left( x+\dfrac{b}3\right)^2 - \left(\dfrac{b}3 \right)^2\right) + 12\\
& = 3 \left(x+\dfrac{b}3\right)^2 + 12 - \dfrac{b^2}3
\end{align}
The minimum value taken by $f'(x)$ is $12-\dfrac{b^2}3$, which we want to be positive. Hence, $$12-\dfrac{b^2}3 > 0 \implies b^2 < 36 \implies -6 < b < 6$$

Comment: I would say that if $b=\pm 6$, then the original function is also strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote,

$$f'(x)=3x^2+2bx^2+12$$

and this is an upwards parabola ($\;3>0\;$) , so if its discriminant is negative it'll
 be positive all the time:

$$\Delta = 4b^2-144<0\iff b^2<36\iff |b|<6$$